# Is the cost of recovering a suicidal person's body deducted from their estate?

Tags: suicide, costs, new-mexico

If a person committed suicide by jumping off a bridge in a remote rural area in New Mexico and it cost the authorities a lot of money to recover their dead body would those costs be deducted from their estate?

Comment: It goes without saying, but please don't do that regardless of the answer to your question.

Comment: If you are considering this course of action please call this number: 800-273-8255.